# Error causado después de hacer una consulta con muchos registros: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Tags: java, tomcat, socket

Estoy ejecutando un programa (JAVA) que inicialmente hace una consulta (a base de datos MySQL) con más de 42,000 registros, esta la hace sin problema, el tema es que después de esta consulta necesito hacer otra, la base de datos es la misma así como la sintaxis (en Java), al intentar hacer la segunda consulta me sale el error

```
** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION  

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2744)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1612)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1332)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1467)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:99)
```

El código que estoy utilizando para ambas consultas es el siguiente

```
Connection cn = null;
        try {
            cn = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(param++, xxxxxx);
            ps.setInt(param++,xxxxxx);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                fecha = rs.getDate("FECHA");
            }
        } catch (SQLException exc) {
            myLogger.error("getUltimoPago", exc);
            throw new ClientesException(exc.getMessage());
        } catch (NamingException exc) {
            myLogger.error("getUltimoPago", exc);
            throw new ClientesException(exc.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (cn != null) {
                    cn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException exc) {
                myLogger.error("getUltimoPago", exc);
                throw new ClientesDBException(exc.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return fecha;
```

Cuando intento reducir la primer consulta con un limit 10 el programa se ejecuta sin problema, cabe mencionar que la base de datos se encuentra en el mismo servidor donde ejecuto mi programa

¿Podrían darme su opinión sobre este problema por favor?

Adjunto los parametros de conexión en Tomcat por si llegase a ser de utilidad

```
<Resource name="jdbc/xxxxxx" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="xxxx" password="xxxxxx" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxxxx?autoReconnect=true" maxActive="50" maxIdle="5" maxWait="30000" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto se resolvió aumentando la memoria del tomcat, para lograr esto seguí las instrucciones de esta pagina

http://training.pensemos.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=16912738

Comment: mira por favor [answer]. podrias explicar un poco mas como hacer eso y porque eso resolvio tu problema?